# Expected "indent", got ";" - Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

How come I get the error:

> expected "indent", got ";"

**EDIT: DISREGARD THE CODE...THE ERROR IS THERE AT THE END OF THE FILE EVEN WHEN I DELETE THAT CODE**

for this code:

```
.modal-open .supreme-container
   -webkit-filter blur(20px)
   -moz-filter blur(20px)
   -o-filter blur(20px)
   -ms-filter blur(20px)
   filter blur(20px)
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a good reason to consider moving to a better pre-processor. Stylus is used by less than 5% of JS projects. The superficially attractive ability to omit colons and brackets and semi-colons is very much a two-edged sword.

Comment: @torazaburo I was just starting to convert my current project to stylus from sass because it seemed more simplistic. I will reconsider.

Comment: @torazaburo, Stylus isn't as used as SASS or Less but is a very good CSS prepocessor, recommend not to use it doesn't seem to me a solution for the concrete problem of the OP. 
BeniaminoBaggins make sure you dont have any spaces or tabs in the line 88.

Comment: @blonfu It was not a solution, it was a comment.